# Oracle hierarchy data representation ambiguity

Tags: oracle10g

I am having a table in following structure.

```
_________________________________
|| ExpObjkey   Exp1    Exp2  operator||
________________________________
    1            2        3    +
    2            4        5    +
    3            6        7    -
```

I want to have records  in the following order:
for expObjKey=1, we will have

```
ExpObjKey Expression
   1       (4+5)+(6-7)
```

explanation:

```
for ExpObjKey 1 we will have 2 +3
then 2 will have 4+5
and 3 will have 6+7.
```

Its more like a hierarchy.

I have tried lots of possible ways but no near the solution.

```
 SELECT expObjkey,  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(exp1||' ' ||operator|| exp2||')', ' (  ') "Path"
 FROM bpmn_expression 
 CONNECT BY PRIOR   
 exp1=expObjkey   or exp2=expObjkey   
start with expObjkey=1
```

Comment: the depth can go to n-level. and of course the real situation is more complicated than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a hierarchical query, but I'd be interested to be proven wrong. You'd need to start at the bottom of the tree and work your way up to allow the substitutions to happen; but then there doesn't seem to be a way to combine the partial expressions that produces. It might be possible with recursive subquery factoring, but that isn't available until 11gR2.

On 10g you could use your own recursive function to generate what you need:

```
create or replace function get_expression(p_key bpmn_expression.expobjkey%type)
return varchar2 is
  row bpmn_expression%rowtype;
begin
  select * into row from bpmn_expression where expobjkey = p_key;
  return '(' || get_expression(row.exp1)
    || row.operator || get_expression(row.exp2) || ')';
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return to_char(p_key);
end;
/

select get_expression(1) as expression from dual;

EXPRESSION                   
------------------------------
((4+5)+(6-7))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53873/1).

You can strip the outer parentheses with trim or regexp_replace if you want to, but they may be acceptable.

If you add another layer, say a record with values `7, 8, 9, '*'`, this would give:

```
EXPRESSION                   
------------------------------
((4+5)+(6-(8*9)))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4eb0d/1).

But this isn't going to be very efficient against a large data set, since it will do a lot of single-row look-ups.

Comment: the above procedure is returning the exact output as I require.